# SANS Forensic Course -worth it?

Tags: certificates, professional-education, forensics, career

I'm a Security Student at Pennsylvania State University and I am considering taking FOR408 through SANS this summer in Pittsburgh (not far from my home). I really want this to help me stand out in my resume and plus I'm just interested. The cost is not an issue. As for my current skill level I spoke with my security professor and he felt that I would be able to handle the work. I would really appreciate any feedback or opinions that anyone could offer me.

Comment: Sorry to close on you, but the value of a certification is very subjective.